# Simple C++ code to generate Armstrong numbers

Tags: c++, sequences

The following is my simple attempt at generating [Armstrong numbers](http://oeis.org/A005188). But it only outputs "1". What might be wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
#include<iostream.h>

int main() 
{ 
    clrscr();
    int r; 
    long int num = 0, i, sum = 0, temp; 

    cout << "Enter the maximum limit to generate Armstrong number "; 
    cin >> num;
    cout << "Following armstrong numbers are found from 1 to " << num << "\t \n"; 

    for(i=1;i<=num;i++) 
    { 
        temp = i; 
        while( temp != 0 ) 
        { 
            r = temp%10; 
            sum = sum + r*r*r; 
            temp = temp / 10; 
        } 

        if ( i == sum ) {
            cout << i;
            sum = 0; 
        }
    } 

    getch(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to limit your usage of comma operators.

Comment: My problem is all solved but the answers are all scattered.. which should be the right answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to always set `sum = 0` inside the for-i-loop.

Comment: look carefully he is setting 'sum =0'

Comment: @Ashot: not always, only if `i == sum`.

Comment: Ok i got it.. so I was resetting the sum ONLY when i==sum becomes true.. my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

> Armstrong  numbers: n-digit numbers equal to sum of n-th powers of their digits.

From your code

```
sum = sum + r*r*r;
```

'r*r*r' isn't n'th power of the number.

Comment: @Power-Inside no it's not correct

Comment: Sorry yes, there is a problem.. thanks for pointing it out.. im very hasty

Comment: @Power-Inside have a look at my answer. calculate the `n` using `log` function.

Answer (score 2):

you can calculate n using log:

```
n = log(i)+1
```

then calculate `r^n` correctly and use it in your summation: `sum += r^n;`. r*r*r is not the correct way of calculating it.

Comment: log(i) from `<math.h>`in C and C++ is logarithm base e=2.718..., not base 10!

Comment: yes thanks, I was all the time debugging my code with 3 digit limit numbers so that is why this did not notice the problem

Comment: @rene How should I approach the log function then? I've never used it in c++ before. Please advice if you may

Comment: you can either use `log10` or `log(i)/log(10)` depending what you have available :)

Comment: I found it.. its log10() function under math.h header.. thanks

Comment: @Power-inside: Use a loop instead of `log()`, see my answer.

Comment: @duedl0r : Since `log()` uses floating point numbers, which are known to be inexact. That's not good when calculation an integer problem. Fairly enough, you also shouldn't use `pow(r,n)` (not `r^n`) then...

Comment: @Rene I found this one better and smaller fragment of coding because im only trying to find out Base 10 Armstrong numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is that you're assuming that n (as in the nth power) is always three (in your `r*r*r`). That's only true if your initial value has three digits (as with the 153 example).

You need to count the digits in your initial number to calculate n, and then replace your `r*r*r` with raising r to the nth power.

This doesn't explain why 153 isn't found, though. The reason for that is because you aren't reseting `sum` to zero *unless* you find a match. You need to reset it to zero whether you found a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works with `n=3` : `sum = sum + r*r*r;`

You must use the `pow()` function (http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/pow.php) to compute powers. (Or create a custom one.)

Comment: Well, strictly, it works for the value 1, because 1 to the nth power is always 1 irrespective of the value of n.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the right, but partial answers:

```
// #include <math.h>

for (long int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
{ 
    long int n = 0, sum = 0;  //  <--- here 
    long ing temp = i; 
    while ( temp != 0 ) 
    { 
        ++n;
        temp /= 10; 
    } 

    temp = i; 
    while ( temp != 0 ) 
    { 
        int r = temp%10; 
        sum += int(pow(double(r), n)); // <-- here
        temp /= 10; 
    } 
    if ( i == sum ) 
    {
        cout << i;
        sum = 0; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Power-inside, I saw your code, its difficult to change your code and edit it, but I have written a similar code to generate Armstrong numbers in a given limit, and it works fine.
Here it is....

```
  #include<iostream.h>
  #include<conio.h>
    class arm
       {
    int a;
    public:
       void display();
        };
     void arm::display()
          {
             cout<<"Enter any number to find armstrong numbers less than it";
             cin>>a;
              for(int i=a;i>=1;i--)
            {
              int d=i;
              int b=i;
              int c=i;
              int count=0;
                while(b!=0)
                    {
                      b=b/10;
                      count++;
                    }
                   int l,m;
                   m=0;
                for(int k=1;k<=count;k++)
               {
                  l=c%10;
                   c=c/10;
                   m=m+l*l*l;
                }



              if(d==m)

              cout<<d<<"\t";

             }

              }


            void main()
              {
                 arm k;
                 k.display();
                 getch();
                }
```